# Hover in thumbnail changes a bigger div with CSS

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have 2 `div` elements. A bigger one (in the top) for the text content and a smaller one (in the bottom) for the thumbnails of the images.

When i hover the images in the thumbnail div, i want to display the image in the bigger `div`, over the text content.

Following is a screenshot without the hover:

[image]

During the hover (Hovering the image on the thumbnail to get bigger in most div):
[image]

Basic structure:

```
<div id="content">

 <p>Lorem ipsum...</p>
  <div id="thumbnail">
  <img src=""../>
</div>

</div><!--content-->
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I'm having a hard time translating the Spanish. Is the thumbnail a child of the parent div?

Comment: I'm sorry, I thought I had posted the translated version

Comment: @NGTHM4R3 can you post the HTML / CSS you have until now? it will help people to provide a solution!

Comment: kinda of this:

<div id="content">
<p>Lorem ipsum...<p>
<div id="thumbnail>
<img src="" /> ....
</div>
</div><!--content-->

Comment: I'll edit the post...

Comment: The text have a certain min-height, so it can be overwrite, or i can create a div just for the bigger images

Comment: have you seen my update on the answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use sibiling selector `~` to hover and do something like this:

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 350px;
}
.main {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0
}
.thumb {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.thumb:hover ~ .main {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <!-- Thumbs -->
  <div class="thumb">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/250x100" />
  </div>
  <!-- Main image -->
  <div class="main">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

#### update JS version only to get hover delayed

```js
$(function() {
  $(".thumb").hover(function() {
      $(this).siblings(".main").fadeIn();
    },
    function() {
      $(this).siblings(".main").fadeOut();
    });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  position: relative;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 350px;
}
.main {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0
}
.thumb {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
  <!-- Thumbs -->
  <div class="thumb">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/100x100" />
  </div>
  <!-- Main image -->
  <div class="main">
    <img src="http://placehold.it/500x200" />
  </div>
</div>
```

> When I add another image that is above the first, and my question is
>   regarding the amount of images that will fit, because usually slides
>   have the numbering of ids so as not to conflict ....

```js
$(function() {
  $(".thumb img").hover(function() {
      var id = this.id.substring(this.id.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
      $("#main-" + id).fadeIn();
    },
    function() {
      var id = this.id.substring(this.id.lastIndexOf('-') + 1);
      $("#main-" + id).fadeOut();
    });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
    position: relative;
    border: 1px solid red;
    height: 350px;
}
.main {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0
}
.main img {
    display: none;
}
.thumb-wrap {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    width:100%;
}
.thumb {
    float:left;
    margin-right:1%
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrap">
    <!-- Thumbs -->
    <div class="thumb-wrap">
        <div class="thumb">
            <img id="thumb-01" src="http://placehold.it/100x100/f00" />
        </div>
        <div class="thumb">
            <img id="thumb-02" src="http://placehold.it/100x100/ff0" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Main image -->
    <div class="main">
        <img id="main-01" src="http://placehold.it/500x200/f00" />
    </div>
    <div class="main">
        <img id="main-02" src="http://placehold.it/500x200/ff0" />
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great, but it is too fast, how can i do a :active effect and close after? again, thanks!

Comment: I think in this case you might need to use some javascript or javascript framework/library.

Comment: hm, got it, there's some way to slow it with css?

Comment: see updated answer, sorry for late reply, some work to do meanwhile

Comment: I have not tested yet, but will have no confusion with id of the images? only put in order?

Comment: didn't understand what you mean, sorry.

Comment: When I add another image that is above the first, and my question is regarding the amount of images that will fit, because usually slides have the numbering of ids so as not to conflict ....

Comment: I have not tested it, but always have to add a rule in the CSS to another picture? if a thumb3? for example...

Comment: in this case just for thumbs yes.

Comment: Then it is not feasible for me because my system will pick up the images automatically ....

Comment: is [this](http://jsfiddle.net/or945udr/) good for you? in this fiddle you don't need to add rules for each thumb.

Comment: it wotks, i really apreciate it! .. you can edit the answer for i mark as solved!

Comment: Sorry open it again, it is that I was a time without coding, and was testing the code and when the page loads the image is already sample, only when I move the mouse on the thumbnail disappears and it begins to function normally ...